# Finer control over Django timeuntil output possible?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently using the [timeuntil](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timeuntil) tag to show an items expiration date. It's currently spitting out...

```
{{rental_till|timeuntill}}
```

Which produces...

```
3 months, 1 week
```

Is it possible to get it to just show, the months, for example? Or any type of finer control over the output format, similar to the [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date) tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only show months, you could [write a simple template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that splits the string on the comma, and returns the first item of the resulting list. The filter code would look like this:

```
from django.template import Library
register = Library()

@register.filter
def split_timeuntil(duration):
    return duration.split(",")[0]
```

Then in your template: `{{rental_till|timeuntil|split_timeuntil}}`

However, the `timeuntil` filter does not have the kind of formatting `date` has. You can easily create a custom filter that returns the format you want by copying the `timeutil` code in `django/template/defaultfilters.py` and `django/utils/timesince.py`.

Comment: inspired on your approach, I've created a more flexible approach: https://gist.github.com/george-silva/6d13219cb23f3fa3f978

Answer (score 0):

No, `timeuntil` doesn't have any options, but you can simply create your own templatetag based on `timeuntil` and make it do whatever you like. See: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3/django/template/defaultfilters.py (line 729)